# How does Tensorflow `tf.train.Optimizer` compute gradients?

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow

I'm following the Tensorflow mnist tutorial (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py).

The tutorial uses `tf.train.Optimizer.minimize` (specifically `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`). I don't see any arguments being passed in anywhere to define gradients.

Is Tensor flow using numerical differentiation by default?

Is there a way to pass in gradients like you can with `scipy.optimize.minimize`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not numerical differentiation, it's [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation). This is one of the main reasons for tensorflow's existence: by specifying operations in a tensorflow graph (with operations on `Tensor`s and so on), it can automatically follow the chain rule through the graph and, since it knows the derivatives of each individual operation you specify, it can combine them automatically.

If for some reason you want to override that piecewise, it's possible with [`gradient_override_map`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Graph.gradient_override_map).

Comment: Isn't automatic differentiation using numerical differentitation?

Comment: @BYOR No; check out the Wikipedia link above. What tensorflow does is actually somewhere in between "real" reverse-mode autodiff and symbolic differentiation, though.

Comment: @Dougal im using eager mode with no graph, no tf.function decorator, how does the auto differentation know the relation between tensors?

Comment: @datdinhquoc It's the same fundamental algorithm, just a little more complicated of an implementation.

Answer (score 10):

It uses automatic differentiation, where it uses the chain rule and goes backward in the graph assigning gradients.

Let’s say we have a tensor, C. C  has made after a series of operations (adding, multiplying, going through some nonlinearity, etc.)

So if C depends on some set of tensors called Xk, we need to get the gradients.

Tensorflow always tracks the path of operations; the sequential behavior of the nodes and how data flow between them. That is done by the graph:
[image]

If we need to get the derivatives of the cost w.r.t inputs X, what this will first do is load the path from X to the cost by extending the graph.

Then it starts in the reverse order, distributing the gradients with the chain rule (same as backpropagation).

Anyway if you read the source code belonging to `tf.gradients()` you can find that Tensorflow has done this gradient distribution part in a nice way.

While backtracking tf interact with graph, in the backward pass TF will meet different nodes. Inside these nodes there are operations which we call "ops" (matmal, softmax,relu, batch_normalization, etc.)

So what tf does is it automatically load these ops in to the graph.

This new node compose the partial derivative of the operations. `get_gradient()`

Let’s talk a bit about these newly added nodes

Inside these nodes tf adds 2 things:

1. Derivative we calculated earlier
2. Inputs to the corresponding "op" in the forward pass

So by the chain rule we can calculate similar to the backpropagation API.

So Tensorflow always thinks about the order of the graph in order to do automatic differentiation.

So as we know we need forward pass variables to calculate the gradients
then we need to store intermidiate values also in tensors. This can reduce the memory. For many operations tf knows how to calculate gradients and distribute them.

Comment: im using eager mode with no graph, no tf.function decorator, how does the auto differentation know the relation between tensors?